# what is sequence_length field in tf.contrib.seq2seq.TrainingHelper?

Tags: tensorflow, seq2seq

Can anyone explain the purpose of sequence length field in `tf.contrib.seq2seq.TrainingHelper`

Answer (score 2):

It represents the length of each target sequence in "inputs" parameter.

Check : http://higepon.hatenablog.com/entry/20171212/1513076578 for example.

It is used for checking if the target sequence tokens exhausted, when feeding each token to decoder. Check the following:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.10/tensorflow/contrib/seq2seq/python/ops/helper.py#L244

Comment: kindly consider adding the information provided in the link in your answer,

Comment: Guys it's like sequence length, like something you provide in dynamic rnn, so you know that's the end of the sequence.